# What is console-kit-daemon for?

Tags: process

I am running Ubuntu in console mode. Do I need console-kit-daemon to be started?
What is it doing? Why is it necessary?
Can I turn it off?
How can I turn it off?
And so on...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. ConsoleKit only manages console logins in graphical mode, so if you're not running X or a desktop environment it's OK to turn it off.

Here's a comment from [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/160612/console-kit-daemon-can-it-be-stopped) showing how to disable console-kit-daemon:

> To disable graphical mode console logins, you can remove
>   /etc/X11/default-display-manager. Stop the running instance with `stop gdm`

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I've been stopping console-kit-daemon on our servers where we don't use graphical logins. Didn't notice any issues. But one thing I wonder about, would X forwarding still work if we needed to use it?

Comment: Yes, X forwarding should work fine to a server with no desktop manager.